# How to color numeric text?

Tags: formatting, openoffice-calc

I have an OpenOffice Calc document that contains text data in cells.  The text in each cell contains numeric characters. I want these numeric characters to be different in color.

Is there a way to accomplish this format?

There are huge number of cells and manually editing would be time consuming. I could not manage to do it by "conditional formatting". So I'd like to learn if any other method is available.

Answer (score -1):

Double-click in the cell and select one of the characters.  Then click on the triangle of the *Font Color* toolbar icon. [image: font color icon]    Finally, choose the color from the palette.

[image: font color palette]